# Unity - can't understand why variables have such values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I change the damage that is used in the bullet, I don't understand why I get such values ​​in console.

When damage is increased project crashes with this error:

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
> System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException (System.Boolean overflow, System.String overflowResourceKey) (at :0)
> System.Number.ParseSingle (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles styles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) (at :0)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
public float _damage;//_damage = 1

private float _currentDamage;

private void Start()
{
    _currentDamage = _damage;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Enemy enemy))
    {
        enemy.GetDamage(_currentDamage);// works right and attacks by value of _damage
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

public void IncreaseDamage(float damageMultiplier)
{
    float damageLong = _currentDamage * damageMultiplier;

    Debug.Log(_currentDamage + " " + damageMultiplier);//shows: 0 1.2

    string str = damageLong.ToString("#.##");

    Debug.Log(str);//shows: "nothing"

    _currentDamage = float.Parse(str);
}
}
```

Comment: Try changing `#.##` to `F2` full line: `string str = damageLong.ToString("F2");`

Comment: Project stopped crushing, but damage doesnt increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the log shows that `_currentDamage` is `0`, also the result of the multiplication

```
float damageLong = _currentDamage * damageMultiplier;
```

will be `0`. And then

```
string str = damageLong.ToString("#.##")
```

gives an empty string, because the `#` placeholder does not print leading or trailing zeros ... And then finally, of course also `float.Parse(str)` fails, because an empty string cannot be parsed to a `float`.

Question is, why is `_currentDamage` equal to `0`? It's because neither of your `_currentDamage` nor `_damage` is initialized to a specific value, thus they both keep their default value `0`.

So unless you initialize `_damage` to something different from `0` outside of this script and *before*  `Start()` is executed (or you remove the comments and initialize `public float _damage = 1`), your `IncreaseDamage` will never work (ie it won't increase the damage) even if you fix your string formatting to

```
string str = damageLong.ToString("F2"); //this will give you a float formated to two decimal places
```

Comment: I initialize _damage value in inspector, but as i understand main problem will happen because this script attached to bullet which appears and get destroyed with its script, so value _currentDamage won't be recorded anywhere, my idea was to increase damage other time but for every bullet its going to be different value as i understand, so i should change construction of increasing damage.